# Constructing a formal proof of certain logical arguments

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given the following arguments:

$ \tag A (R \to \neg S) \land  (T \to \neg U)$

$ \tag B (V\to \neg W) \land  (X \to \neg Y)$

$ \tag C (T \to  W) \land  (U \to  S)$

$ \tag D V \lor R $

$$ \therefore \neg T \lor \neg U $$

how to prove  this using the standard [rules of inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference)?

Answer (score 2):

One expects this to follow more or less  directly from $(A)$ because $p\to q\iff \neg p \lor q$.
However, there is no *tertium no datur*.
One has to find ones luch starting from (D) by case analysis:

By *simplification* from (A):
$$\tag{1}R\to\neg S$$
and 
$$\tag2 T\to\neg U$$
By *simplification* from (C):
$$\tag{3}T\to W$$
and 
$$\tag4 U\to S$$
By *modus ponens* from (1):
$$\tag 5R\vdash \neg S$$
By *modus tollens* from  (4) and (5):
$$\tag 6 R\vdash \neg U$$
By *addition* from (6)
$$\tag 7 R\vdash \neg T \lor \neg U$$
By *decuction theorem* from (6):
$$\tag 8 R\to (\neg T \lor \neg U)$$
By *simplification* from (B):
$$\tag 9 V\to\neg W$$
By *modus ponens* from (9):
$$\tag{10} V\vdash \neg W$$
By *modus tollens* from (10) and (3):
$$\tag{11}V\vdash \neg T$$
By *addition* from (11):
$$\tag{12}V\vdash \neg T\lor\neg U$$
By *deduction theorem* from (12)
$$\tag{13}V\to( \neg T\lor\neg U)$$
By *case analysis* from (D), (13) and (8):
$$\neg T \lor \neg U_\blacksquare$$

Comment: Thanks, but I am not accustomed with sequent notation, so I couldn't understand some parts of your solution. Could you please edit it or perhaps suggest me some reference?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using a [Fitch-style proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/):

[image]

The first four lines state the premises. I then attempt to consider both cases in premise 4 by assuming each in a subproof and deriving the desired goal. When that is done I can use [disjunction elimination or case analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) (vE) on line 17 to complete the proof.

Within the subproofs I used [conjunction elimination or simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) (∧E), [conditional elimination or modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) (→E), [disjunction introduction or addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) (vI) and [modus tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) (MT).

All rules are listed on the OP's [rules of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference).

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/